# What exactly are the differences between Kickstart 1.2 and 1.3?

Tags: amiga, amiga-kickstart

The only very known difference is that Kickstart 1.3 fixes the silly bug that prevented Kickstart 1.2 to boot from a hard disk (a routine in the boot code uses A6 loaded with an incorrect library base, thus ending up being a NOOP and skipping AutoConfig'ed DOSNode's). However, are there other changes?

(This question is only about Kickstart, not about differences on Workbench disks, which were bigger)

Comment: here a link to a description how to make autoboot work even in Kick 1.2: http://eab.abime.net/showthread.php?t=77299

Answer (score 4):

Kickstart 1.3 changed the file system to avoid extra disk space waste "due to the fact it could store only 488 bytes in any block of 512 bytes keeping 24 bytes for checksums."[<sup>1</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AmigaOS_versions#Kickstart.2FWorkbench_1.0.2C_1.1.2C_1.2.2C_1.3)

1.3 also added a new archive flag to the `protect` command, a `PASSKEY` parameter to the `LOCK DRIVE` command, and the `Hidden (H), Script (S), Pure (P)` parameters to the `PROTECT FILE` command.[<sup>2</sup>](https://archive.org/stream/1991-kerkloh-tornsdorf-zoller-amigados-inside-and-out/1991-kerkloh-tornsdorf-zoller-amigados-inside-and-out_djvu.txt)

Those are the only main differences I can find between Kickstart 1.2 and 1.3.  There might be a few more but I doubt there was anything more substantial than the hard disk boot bugfix.

Comment: I would not refer to the 488/512 bytes per block issue as a bug. AFAIK it was just that the OFS was designed with way too much consideration for data integrity than what was needed at that point in history (i.e. floppies and hard disk were already reliable enough not to require data checksumming), not to say that checksum calculation lowered throughput. So Commodore designed an improved filesystem that got rid of that. Are the additional flags supported by Kick 1.2 already, just there was no way to set/reset them?

Comment: Indeed, the second link in JAL's answer points to the fact that:

Comment: @user180940 Thanks, I've attempted to refactor my answer.  I'm no expert on this, just trying to provide some resource for you.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Indeed, by reading your second link it looks like that: "The H and A bits function only with Kickstart 1.3." and that PASSKEY requires Kickstart 1.3. So I guess the S bit really is taken into consideration by the Shell ("Shell-Seg", which under 1.x is on disk) and not by the ROM resident CLI code, am I remembering it right?

Comment: It was *Workbench* 1.3 that came with FastFileSystem, which could be soft-loaded, typically onto hard disks; the ROM filesystem could still only read OFS-formatted disks. The ROM filesystem gained FFS support in Kickstart 2.0.

Comment: Does the kickstart OFS support the H and A flags in 1.2 ?

Comment: No Kickstart ever implemented hiding files and according to other sources, the `H` bit wasn’t even meant to mean “hidden”, but “hold”, with an entirely different purpose. Anyway, the only perceivable effect was printing “H” in file information when the bit has been set.

Answer (score 3):

The autobooting feature that Kickstart 1.3 added allowed e.g. booting from the RAM drive `RAD:` after a reset ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiga_Fast_File_System#History)).

One could e.g. boot Workbench 1.3 on a Kickstart 1.2 Amiga and create `RAD:`, but it wouldn't boot from it after a reset (own experiment many years ago).

Comment: Autobooting in general.  1.2 won't autoboot hard drives either, 1.3 will.